# How to compile Cmake file with Android.mk?

Tags: android, c++, x86, cmake, arm

I need to generate `ARM` structure shared library for a sample`CPP` project.

Sample projects contains:

- CMakeLists.txt
- some.cpp (s)
- Some.h (s)
- some.tab.cpp.make (S)
- some.tab.hpp.cmake (s)

Now, I want to create a shared library for a different Android project. I tried to compile with `[Android-Cmake][1]`but it is generating `X86` Architecture library not ARM.

Please let me know if there is another way to do it. Also can i run `X86` on Android Platform for all version?

## Edit :

Here is my Android.mk:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)/../   //Path is according JNI Folder
SRC_TOP_DIR := $(LOCAL_PATH)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE := smileParse
LOCAL_CFLAGS := -DANDROID

LOCAL_SRC_FILES := main.cpp test.cpp smamain.cpp
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/../include $(LOCAL_PATH)/
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a folder called JNI in your project:

[image]

Create or Edit Android.mk in JNI folder, set include and library path,

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE    := hello-jni
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := some.cpp
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

Declare a java wrapper class, declare a native function:

```
public class JWrapperSomeClass {
    public native void Demo(int para);
}
```

use **javah** command to generate the function signature for your C++ method wrapper:

```
javah -jni -classpath bin/classes/ -d jni com.example.Your.Package.Class
```

Edit the code in C++

Go to your project folder, run command:

```
$ANDROID_NDK/ndk-build
```

where $ANDROID_NDK is the folder where you installed android NDK

That is pretty much it. For more details, you might read NDK or JNI documentation.

Comment: David, Please have a look at Edit section in Question. I have added all required `.cpp` and `.h` files in `Android.mk` file. But there are  a lot of dependecies written in `Cmake.txt`. How so i run them? or How should it into `Android.mk`?

Comment: If you have already had cpp files, then add all needed cpp files in Android.mk, then run the ndk-build cmd will do. The cmake is used to generated the needed cpp/header or other files. Do not confuse yourself with cmake and ndk-build. They serve different purposes.

Comment: Thanks but one more question, These cpp are written in pure cpp code not in Java JNICPP. Will that affect?

Sample of CPP file: https://github.com/rdkit/rdkit/blob/master/Code/GraphMol/Atom.cpp

Comment: These cpp files cannot be directly called in Java. You have to offer java wrapper methods, in which you call cpp functions. Note th **native** keyword in the answer, it indicated that the function **Demo** is **NOT** a pure java function, but implemented in c++! This naming of this c++ function follows specific format, and you'd better have a look at JNI documentation.

Comment: How to add multiple .c, .h, .hpp files all together in Android.mk as LOCAL_SRC_FILES?   
Thanks in advance.